# Ruby: counters, counting and incrementing

Tags: ruby, irb

If you have seen my previous questions, you'd already know I am a big nuby when it comes to Ruby. So, I discovered this website which is intended for C programming, but I thought whatever one can do in C, must be possible in Ruby (and more readable too).

The challenge is to print out a bunch of numbers. I discovered this nifty method .upto() and I used a block (and actually understanding its purpose). However, in IRb, I got some unexpected behavior.

```
class MyCounter
    def run 
    1.upto(10) { |x| print x.to_s + " " } 
    end
end


irb(main):033:0> q = MyCounter.new
=> #<MyCounter:0x5dca0>
irb(main):034:0> q.run
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 => 1
```

I have no idea where the => 1 comes from :S Should I do this otherwise? I am expecting to have this result:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Thank you for your answers, comments and feedback!

Comment: Why don't you try a website which is intended for Ruby?

Comment: Why doesn't Oscar Reyes stop posting?

Comment: This website is pretty good and I can read C code as long it doesn't gets crazy enough. Besides, it looked pretty retro.

Comment: @NSD I beg your pardon? :P   @Shyam Sounds interesting, could you provide the link?

Comment: http://www.inf.bme.hu/contest/tasks/

Comment: @Shyam: Nice.... There's something funny there. That page has been accessed 3097 times since 1996. It is either a very rare page, or the counter have turn around already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I have no idea where the => 1 comes from*

Don't worry. By default `irb` prints the returning value of the execution of the method.

Even if you don't write the `return` statement  ( like in C for instance ) Ruby returns the value of the last computed statement.

In this case it was 1

That's all.

For instance try:

```
class WhereIsTheReturn
    def uh?
        14 * 3 # no return keyword
    end
end


whereIsIt = WhereIsTheReturn.new
hereItIs = whereIsIt.uh?
print "Here it is : #{hereItIs}\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

The "=> 1" is from IRB, not your code. After every statement you type into IRB, it prints the result of that statement after a "=>" prompt.

Try printing a newline in your function:

```
def run 
  1.upto(10) { |x| print x.to_s + " " }
  print "\n"
end
```

Then it'll look like this:

```
irb> q.run
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  => nil
```

Comment: @jeremy: It actually print `=> nil` which is the result of executing : `print "\n"` I have udpated your answer to reflect this.

Comment: you're welcome @Shyam, and thankyou @Oscar... obviously I didn't actually test it out :P